# Can I switch back?

Tags: windows-10

If I were to download this would I be able to switch back to my Windows 10 operating system? I am thinking about switching ,but have been told that it takes a lot of technological knowledge. I am decent with technology, but am a little weary of my "coding" abilities. I would like to know if it would be possible to switch back if I can't understand the Linux OS. Please help. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out "Linux live CDs" to try the OS without actually installing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Answer (score 1):

You will lose any saved data, but yes you can switch back to windows if you want to. You might want to consider downloading VirtualBox for windows and installing ubuntu inside of a virtual machine, that way you will get to try ubuntu from within windows. You get a nice taste of a linux environment without the risk.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to choose one or other my friend if you are not sure Ubuntu is for you I would recommend using the live CD, or dual booting Ubuntu next to windows so you can go back to windows anytime! Best luck! ( You will not lose any windows data or system files with these options!) http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you intend to do with Ubuntu, but it definitely does not take " a lot of technological knowledge". Unless you want or need to do something very specific with your computer, or make a daily use of non-native software, Ubuntu is quite intuitive and easy to learn. You might have to change some habits, but it's no big deal.

If you want to keep both windows and Ubuntu for a while before complete switching, [dual-boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) is an option, although it might requires more technological knowledge. Testing with a [live-cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) is another option.

I suggest you do some reading on official documentation, installation and first-step tutorials before trying. Make a list of the software you regularly use, and see if they are available in Ubuntu, or if they have an equivalent available (for example, Microsoft Office > LibreOffice). You'll see that most of them (Skype, Steam, Firefox, Google Chrome, VLC, etc.) are available.